# Зачем в Android нужны Resources?

Tags: android, resources

Зачем вообще нужны ресурсы? И почему принято выносить строки в `res/strings`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того чтобы задавать альтернативные ресурсы для разных конфигураций устройств и текущих настроек ОС, не изобретая велосипеды с выбором подходящего ресурса.
То же и про строки - переводы на разные языки просто добавляются в соответствующие папки и при запросе выбираются автоматически.